# Trouble with Bootstrap in Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

live link. www.velnikolic.com/little

```css
    /* Radial Out */
      .hvr-radial-out {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
          -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
          background: #e1e1e1;
          -webkit-transition-property: color;
          transition-property: color;
          -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
      }
      .hvr-radial-out:before {
          content:"";
          position: absolute;
          z-index: -1;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background: #2098d1;
          border-radius: 100%;
          -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
          -webkit-transition-property: transform;
          transition-property: transform;
          -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
          transition-duration: 0.3s;
          -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
          transition-timing-function: ease-out;
      }
      .hvr-radial-out:hover, .hvr-radial-out:focus, .hvr-radial-out:active {
          color: white;
      }
      .hvr-radial-out:hover:before, .hvr-radial-out:focus:before, .hvr-radial-out:active:before {
          -webkit-transform: scale(2);
          transform: scale(2);
      }
      .hvr-pulse {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
          -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
          -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      }
      .hvr-pulse:hover, .hvr-pulse:focus, .hvr-pulse:active {
          -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pulse;
          animation-name: hvr-pulse;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" title="Art &amp; Design Center" href="http://velnikolic.com/little">
            <img class="logo img-responsive" src="http://velnikolic.com/little/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-child/img/logo.png" />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <ul class="cartnav nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/cart/"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          </ul>
          <ul id="menu-home" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li id="menu-item-61" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item active"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/about/">About</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-215" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Facility<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-124" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/rental/">Rental</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/events/">Events</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-28" class="dropdown menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/gallery/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Gallery<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-238" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/art/">Art</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-233" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/videos/">Videos</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/247-2/">Rooms</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/shop/">Art Store</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://velnikolic.com/little/contact/">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>


        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- end .container -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .navbar -->


    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl hvr-radial-out hvr-pulse"><i class="fa fa-camera"><br/><span class="icon-text">Gallery</span></i>
    </button>
```

First and main problem is that the logo gets shifted out of place in IE and Safari.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Not sure how to troubleshoot as IE does not have a console.

The second problem is that the icons in the center of the page do not animate as they do on the other browsers. In IE they simply turn the background to clear and the text-color to white.

In Safari they work a little bit better, but they turn the circle into a square and then back into a circle.

If there is no way to make the animations the same, can I disable them only for safari and ie?

Comment: Holy wall of HTML and CSS, Batman! Ain't nobody got time for that. Please make your question a bit more terse.

Comment: IE's developer tools are toggled via the F12 key.